# I am trying to replace a string with other from function.php

Tags: php, functions

I am trying to replace `class="fa fa-play mi"` with `class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"`  but no success.

```
echo str_replace( '<i class="fa fa-play mi"></i>');
```

with:

```
<i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your query

Comment: please see update question

Answer (score 2):

The [`str_replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) function should have 3 parameters, so your code should be like this:

```
echo str_replace(
    'class="fa fa-play mi"',
    'class="fa fa-play mi" aria-hidden="true"',
    '<i class="fa fa-play mi"></i>'
);
```

Comment: but this is not working , can you convert this with filter hook

Comment: Hi. You didn't explain anything about your situation, you just asked for replace. Please add details about where and how are you trying to do this. It's not possible to answer it without knowing this.